How to delete a session token cookie in production on NextJS 14?
I have this function on the server side to delete the auth cookie token when the user logs out. It works fine on the development mode, but when it doesn't delete the cookie in the production mode. Why is it?
export async function logout() {
    cookies().set('session', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
}


Here is how the cookie is set when the user signs in:
cookies().set('session', session, {expires: expires, httpOnly: true, sameSite: true});
Before I used cookies().delete('session') function, but upon research I changed it to set the value to empty string, and expire the cookie. This still didn't fix. Thanks in advance!
